# Is this code vulnerable to buffer overflow?

Tags: c, overflow, buffer-overflow

Fortify reported a buffer overflow vulnerability in below code citing following  reason -

In this case we are primarily concerned with the case **"Depends upon properties of the data that are enforced outside of the immediate scope of the code."**, because we cannot verify the safety of the operation performed by memcpy() in abc.cpp

```
void create_dir(const char *sys_tmp_dir,  const char *base_name,
                size_t     base_name_len)
{
    char        *tmp_dir;
    size_t      sys_tmp_dir_len;

    sys_tmp_dir_len = strlen(sys_tmp_dir);

   tmp_dir = (char*) malloc(sys_tmp_dir_len + 1 + base_name_len + 1);
   if(NULL == tmp_dir) 
     return;

memcpy(tmp_dir, sys_tmp_dir, sys_tmp_dir_len);
tmp_dir[sys_tmp_dir_len] = FN_LIBCHAR;
memcpy(tmp_dir + sys_tmp_dir_len + 1, base_name, base_name_len);
tmp_dir[sys_tmp_dir_len + base_name_len + 1] = '\0';
..........
..........

}
```

It appears to me a false positive since we are getting the size of data first, allocating that much amount of space, then calling memcpy with size to copy.
But I am looking for good reasons to convince fellow developer to get rid of current implementation and rather use c++ strings. This issue has been assigned to him. He just sees this a false positive so doesn't  want to change anything.

*Edit* I see quick, valid criticism of the current code. Hopefully, I'll be able to convince him now. Otherwise, I'll hold the baton. :)

Comment: I guess the warning is because you're relying on `base_name_len` being truthful. As it says, that's not being enforced in the scope of this code. Using something more sensible like `std::string` would fix that.

Comment: Unless there's a reason to think that `base_name` is not a null-terminated string, you could use `memcpy(tmp_dir + sys_tmp_dir_len + 1, base_name, base_name_len + 1);` so `memcpy()` null terminates the string. If `base_name` is not accurate or is not a null-terminated string, then your existing code is safer.  I don't see a problem with buffer overflow if you check the result of `malloc()` — but if you don't think you can trust the strings being passed, then you should check them for nullness.  You can't check them for validity otherwise in a reliable, portable way.

Comment: You've got 8 lines of ugly code there and still need a free, and you can replace it with a `std::string` one-liner making it exception-safe in the process, plus you know it'll shut up a false positive in your tool - what more reason do you need?  If you want to use C, `asprintf()` if it suits your portability needs... concise code can hide fewer bugs and obfuscate less meaningful logic.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes, That's my guess. I know that using std::string will help to get rid of this code at first place. Adriano's comment below makes sense to me.

Comment: It's funny that there are already 3 valid criticisms (Mike Syemour's comment on `base_name_len`, Adriano Repetti's comment on trusting `sys_tmp_dir` and Matt's comment on `malloc` failing,  in just 20 minutes.

Comment: @MSalters  Yeah! Sad part is developer who is assigned to fix the problem is not ready to re-factor the code. He simply sees this a false positive

Answer (score 7):

Take a look to `strlen()`, it has input string but it has not an upper bound then it'll go on searching until it founds `\0`. It's a vulnerability because you'll perform `memcpy()` trusting its result (if it won't crash because of access violation while searching). Imagine:

```
create_dir((const char*)12345, baseDir, strlen(baseDir));
```

You tagged both C and C++...if you're using C++ then `std::string` will *protect* you from these issues.

Comment: True, that's another vulnerability. Will that cause buffer overflow ? What will you call this new vulnerability ?

Comment: I fail to see how the strlen() can lead to a buffer overflow. It can return a very large number which could cause malloc() to fail and lead to a segmentation fault, but the size of the allocated buffer, if it does not fail, will always be large enough to accommodate the write. That said, if it is C++ code, I would definitely use std::string and if it is C code, I would use asfprintf(). As written, it makes my head hurt -- overly complex for the task. (I note that the original question has been edited to add a NULL test on malloc() now - I stand by the overly complex statement)

Comment: @kscottpiel suppose input string pointer for not point to a string but a *code section*. What will happen? What if pointer is just garbage (on purpose)? Result depends on OS (and deamons in your nose). Access violation, trap... Reading is not (much) more safe than writing because it *may* cause a write elsewhere. If this is done in drivers it's even worse.

Answer (score 4):

> It appears to me a false positive since we are getting the size of data first, allocating that much amount of space

This assumption is a problem that matches the warning/error. In your code, you're *assuming* that `malloc` successfully allocated the requested memory. If your system has no memory to spare, `malloc` will fail and return `NULL`. When you try to `memcpy` into `tmp_dir`, you'd be copying to `NULL` which would be bad news.

You should check to guarantee that the value returned by `malloc` is not `NULL` before considering it as a valid pointer.

Comment: Thanks. That NULL check had already been added in code. I missed to add it. If memory allocation fails then simply returning  for now.